# Wildcard self signed SSL cert across many hosts

Tags: ssl, web-server, https

I would like to be able to communicate over SSL with several different devices each which is running a web service.  To expand, on a local network there may be many devices (Raspberry Pi units) which each run a web service.  There is then a centrally hosted Web App which calls the web service on different devices via its IP Address and Port.  I am happy enough to use a Self Signed cert for my needs and communicate with each device by IP/Port, however the difficulty I have is being able to deploy a common certificate on each device that would allow this traffic over SSL.

I don't want to have to create a different cert for each device, I want to be able to create a device image that uses the cert that I can easily deploy to other devices without any further config.

Comment: "*the difficulty I have is being able to deploy a common certificate on each device that would allow this traffic over SSL*": you want to tell us a bit more about this difficulty?

Comment: Each device is communicated via its IP address, I don't believe I can create an SSL cert to cover essentially star.star unless I am mistaken

Comment: Generally, SSL certificates are designed to tie SSL keys to FQDNs, so yes, your life would be a lot easier if you registered a disposable domain (or delegated a subdomain from something you already control) and gave all these servers FQDNs in the same domain.

Comment: I have no control over the domain these devices will eventually end up on so its very difficult to have an FQDN as every site would be different.

Comment: That makes no sense.  You do know their IP addresses, right?  You must, or your original plan won't work either.  Put those IP addresses into a zonefile.  Devices don't *end up on a domain* - that's not how DNS works.

Comment: Sorry to clarify.  The product i am working on is a commercial product. A customer may buy many devices and connect them to their own network.  The device will get its IP by DHCP.   The idea was to make these devices essentially plug and play.  When they are first powered on they make a 'Call Home' call to a central server which maintains a list of all devices and their IPs, then in a Web App running in a browser calls are made to a web service running on each device, hopefully over SSL.

Comment: Well, have that server add the freshly-called-home IP to a zonefile, and the corresponding FQDN to the list of devices to contact.  Or just give the end-devices self-signed certificates, and tell the central server to ignore the certificate errors.  Anyway, aren't you going to have a *big* problem with devices connected to RFC1918 networks?

Comment: So, what happens when this common certificate expires? Or that you need to revoke that certificate for some reason? Sounds like you want to use SSL because "encryption" yet there's no way to trust that you're really talking to the end device and not a man in the middle, so it's pointless.

Comment: I will have a look into the zonefile approach.  My central server may be in the cloud as these devices can also be contacted via the cloud.  My idea is that if the device and users browser are on the same LAN that they talk locally if you like (Its a video streaming app so I want to minimize bandwidth issues).

Answer (score -2):

Have  a look at **Multi-Domain (SAN) Certificates** or **Wildcard SSL Certificates** . These basically allow one to create ssl certificates valid for multiple domains.

Comment: You might want to read the OP's comment above, plus you might note that the title suggests the OP is already familiar with wilcard certificates.  In any case, this doesn't help with the problem as stated.